# Prevent UAC from backup batch file

Tags: windows-7, uac, batch-file

I have created a batch file to backup my files.
I also want to backup the registry.
However when i run the `regedit /e "U:\Backup\Registry\regbackup.reg"` command it pops op the UAC [image: UAC]

Can i disable this; I Want the batch file to run silently.

Here is the batch file.

> @echo off
>
> echo ~~~ Backing up My Documents ~~~
>
> Robocopy C:\Users\josef.vanzyl\Documents U:\Backup\Documents *.*. /E /SEC /MIR /R:2 /W:5
>
> echo ~~~ Backing up the Registry ~~~
>
> if not exist "U:\Backup\Registry" mkdir "U:\Backup\Registry"
>
> if exist "U:\Backup\Registry\regbackup.reg" del "U:\Backup\Registry\regbackup.reg"
>
> regedit /e "U:\Backup\Registry\regbackup.reg"
>
> echo ~~~ Done! ~~~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `reg` instead of `regedit`. `regedit /e` without specifying a key exports all of HLKM and HKCU (I think), so the equivalent would require two commands: `reg export HKLM` and `reg export HKCU`, which would result in two files.

```
@echo off

echo ~~~ Backing up My Documents ~~~

Robocopy C:\Users\josef.vanzyl\Documents U:\Backup\Documents .. /E /SEC /MIR /R:2 /W:5

echo ~~~ Backing up the Registry ~~~

if not exist "U:\Backup\Registry" mkdir "U:\Backup\Registry"

if exist "U:\Backup\Registry\regbackup_HKLM.reg" del "U:\Backup\Registry\regbackup_HKLM.reg"

echo Exporting HKLM

reg export HKLM "U:\Backup\Registry\regbackup_HKLM.reg"

if exist "U:\Backup\Registry\regbackup_HKCU.reg" del "U:\Backup\Registry\regbackup_HKCU.reg"

echo Exporting HKCU

reg export HKLM "U:\Backup\Registry\regbackup_HKCU.reg"

echo ~~~ Done! ~~~
```

There's probably some way to merge them into one file, but it's not really necessary. Also, `reg` can export the following root keys for me on Windows 7 (`reg export /?`):

- `HKLM` HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
- `HKCU` HKEY_CURRENT_USER
- `HKCR` HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
- `HKU`  HKEY_USERS
- `HKCC` HK_CURRENT_CONFIG